# rotate div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to rotate div one time and I tires to use this code

```
$.fn.rotate = function () {
var self = $(this);    

for (var degree = 0; degree <= 360; degree++){
    self.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    self.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'}); 
    self.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'}); 
}
};

$("img").rotate();
```

but it doesn't work at all. 
What wrong? How to make in work?

**upd**
I have found solution, it works

```
$.fn.rotate = function () {
var self = $(this),   
degree = 0;
 var interval = setInterval(function () {
    self.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    self.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'}); 
    self.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
     degree++;
     if (degree === 360) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 5);
};

$("img").rotate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eaQRx/2086/

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: maybe you need to use a timeout between each update to make sure it is displayed on the screen?

Comment: You're rotating it 360 degrees which is the same position it starts in. Seems to work just fine (270 degree rotation example) http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cxeD3/. Also I believe it's `-webkit-transform`.

Comment: I've found solution and added it in my question

Comment: @truslivii.lev you can actually post an answer to your own question. In fact, it is encouraged behavior on this site. Go ahead and add that as an answer and then accept your own answer :).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$.fn.clockwiseRotate = function () {
$(this).each(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        degree = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        self.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        self.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        self.css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        degree++;
        if (degree === 361) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1);
});
};

$.fn.counterclockwiseRotate = function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var self = $(this),
            degree = 360;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
            });
            self.css({
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
            });
            self.css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
            });
            degree--;
            if (degree === -1) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1);
    });
};
$('img:first-child').clockwiseRotate();
$('img:last-child').counterclockwiseRotate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eaQRx/2100/